# Dual Citizenship but I only have one passport — how to use ESTA website?

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, us-visa-waiver-program, applications, australian-citizens

I have dual citizenship (one by Birth) and the other is Australian.
I have lived in Australia for the majority of my life and I only have 1 passport. 
On the ESTA website there is a question for dual citizenship. If I choose yes you must enter the passport number for the second citizenship.

Can I still obtain a visa with ESTA ?

Comment: No, you can't "obtain a visa with ESTA". Nobody can -- ESTA is only for visa-free travel; people who need a visa can and should not use ESTA at all.

Answer (score 52):

From the [ESTA Online Help](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#ata8):

> **What if I have dual citizenship, but my non-VWP passport is expired or I do not have a passport for that country?**
>
> If you have any additional passports, please enter the most recent passport information, even if that passport is expired. If you are a dual citizen but do not have a passport from another country, select the country from the drop down list and do not enter anything in the Passport Number field.